# How to change ImageButton image onclick. My code is not working

Tags: java, android

I can't figure out why my code isn't working.  I've got an ImageButton declared and I'm when the user clicks on the image, I was to increment `valHomeFouls`.  When `valHomeFouls > 5` then it is reset to 0.

For some reason it is not changing the image onClick.

```
    // set the onClick listener for the foulsHome ImageButton
    btnFoulsHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            valFoulsHome++;

            if( valFoulsHome > 5 )
                valFoulsHome = 0;

            switch( valFoulsHome ) {
                case 5:
                    btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls5);
                case 4:
                    btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls4);
                case 3:
                    btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls3);
                case 2:
                    btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls2);
                case 1:
                    btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls1);
                case 0:
                    btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Can anyone see why?

Comment: is valFoulsHome++ declared as a static variable?

Comment: What is `valFoulsHome` initialized to?

Comment: add `break` in each case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot the `break` statements:

```
switch( valFoulsHome ) {
    case 5:
        btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls5);
        break;
    case 4:
        btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls4);
        break;
    case 3:
        btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls3);
        break;
    case 2:
        btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls2);
        break;
    case 1:
        btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls1);
        break;
    case 0:
    default: // You should always have a default case
        btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls0);
}
```

Without `break` statements, the cases "fall through". This means that if `valFoulsHome == 2` the code calls each of these lines:

```
btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls2);
btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls1);
btnFoulsHome.setImageResource(R.drawable.fouls0);
```

Which is not what you want...

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I didn't forget the break statements I was just incorrect about the behavior without them.  I thought that once valFoulsHome == 5 that the others wouldn't trigger because they don't they cases aren't true for 4,3,2,1 or 0 then.  Thank you for correcting me.  It works perfect!